# How update an attribute binded on a check box when clicking on it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, checkbox

First of all, thanks in advance for your attention : I am pretty noob in Rails and I am facing a problem that does not seem difficult but I have some troubles implementing it.

Here is my question : I am displaying a list of "Recommendations" using the following partial :

```
<table class="recommendations" summary="User recommendations">
    <%= render @recommendations%>
</table>
```

It calls the next partial for each of the dispayed "Recommendations" :

```
<tr>
    <td class="recommendations">
 <span class="content">
            <%= wrap(recommendation.content)%>
        </span>
 <span class="timestamp">
            Posted <%=time_ago_in_words(recommendation.created_at)%> ago.
 </span>
    </td>
    <td>
 <%= form_for current_user.recommendations.find(:id => recommendation.id) do |f| %>
     <label>Display</label><%= f.check_box :displayed, :onclick => "update"%>
 <% end %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

So, I would like to bind the recommendation.displayed attribute in the checkbox and update automatically the recommendation resource when the checkbox is checked or not.

For now, I can not access to the appropriate "recommendation" instance to pass to the form_for because I have the following error :

```
Unknown key(s): id
```

And then I am not sure that the

```
:onclick => "update"
```

will perform what I want to do : call the rest "PUT" method to update the resource in database.

Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now I am done.

Rails can manage the checked action on a check_box but not the unchecked one. That explains the previous behaviour.

I changed the way to do that and I used link_to with image_tag. Here is the code :

```
<td>
    <label>Display</label>  
<% if (recommendation.displayed?) %>
<%= link_to image_tag("checked.png", :border=>0), :action => :hide, :id => recommendation %>
<% else %>
<%= link_to image_tag("unchecked.png", :border=>0), :action => :display, :id => recommendation %>
<%end%>
</td>
```

And in the controller :

```
def display
  @recommendation.displayed = true
  unless @recommendation.save
    flash[:error] = "Error displaying the recommendation."
  end
  redirect_back_or current_user 
end

def hide
  @recommendation.displayed = false
  unless @recommendation.save
    flash[:error] = "Error hiding the recommendation."
  end
  redirect_back_or current_user 
end
```

And the specific routes  :

```
get 'recommendations/display/:id', :to => "recommendations#display"
get 'recommendations/hide/:id', :to => "recommendations#hide"
```

Now it works fine.